# Retrieving currentUser data from realtime database

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am having trouble accessing the current user data stored in the realtime database, I can get the information from the user object but nothing stored in additional database stored in the database. I am relatively new at this and this is my first time using Firebase Authentication.[

```js
btnSignup.on("click", function (e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
    email = txtEmail.val();
    password = txtPassword.val();
    auth = firebase.auth();

    // check for real email
    promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    promise.catch(console.log(e.message));
    txtPassword.val("");
    txtEmail.val("");

    userDisplayName = $("#displayName-input").val();

    dietVal = $("input[name='diet']:checked").val();

    database.ref("users/" + userId).set({
        userId: userId,
        userEmail: userEmail,
        displayName: userDisplayName,
        dietVal: dietVal
    });
});

// Logout button click
btnLogout.on("click", function (e) {
    console.log("logged out");
    firebase.auth().signOut();
    $("#navbarDropdown").hide();
});

// User state change if else functions

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (firebaseUser) {
    if (firebaseUser) {
        console.log(firebaseUser);
        $("#dropdown-text").text(firebaseUser.email);
        $("#navbarDropdown").css({
            "display": "block"
        });
        $("#signup-login-button").css({
            "display": "none"
        });

        userId = firebaseUser.uid;
        userEmail = firebaseUser.email;
        userDisplayName = firebaseUser.displayName;

        console.log(firebaseUser.uid);

        //pushing to firebase to save user data.
        // Save changes button click
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: The database screenshot you shared shows the information of two users, and seems to correspond to the code you shared. Did you expect more information in the database? Or is something else about the code not doing what you expected it to do?

Comment: I am trying to be able to use snapshot to pull out the displayName and dietVal to put in a variable so i can use it to narrow search results based on which user is signed in. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: The uid in the user object is different from the one being stored in the realtime database? maybe this is my issue

Comment: Yeah, that seems off. I don't see where in your current code that would happen though. What I do notice is that you're not waiting for your `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` promise to resolve before writing to the database, which seems unusual. You probably want `promise.then(...)` and write to the database within that.

Comment: Yeah that was the only way I have gotten it to pull everything from the sign up page to the database. But to me it seems that the userID is the firebaseUser.uid, but what it is saving is a different number. I have been looking it up and seems like it might be a key

Comment: Hold on, I'm confused now. The keys in your JSON screenshot are he same as the value in `userId` under it, aren't they? So what is the problem in that case?

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work, set the data after the promise. I was also using the variables saved under the logged in user so that is why it wasn't matching up! Thank you for the help!